# LiveCycle Server cannot find font - Output Module

Tags: fonts, adobe, livecycle

I'm using Adobe LiveCycle ES3 with the output Module to merge XDP forms with XML data. The forms are created using LiveCycle Designer. This works all great for PDF files.

Not I wanted to swtich to PDF/A format as result. This doen's work, because the font could not be found the Server:

> (com.adobe.document.xmlform.ReturnStatus@33c0ab2b) XMLForm, render : 20511, Requested font 'Liberation Sans' was not found and font substitution is not allowed for PDF/A.

But the font is installed:

```
root@develop3:~# ls /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-liberation/LiberationSans-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 134548 16. Feb 2011  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-liberation/LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 139008 16. Feb 2011  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-liberation/LiberationSans-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 161020 16. Feb 2011  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-liberation/LiberationSans-Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 139280 16. Feb 2011  /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-liberation/LiberationSans-Regular.ttf
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-liberation/ directory as customer font directory in livecycle admin ui core setting and restart the server and give it a try. You can check [adobe help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/AdminHelp/WS92d06802c76abadb-5145d5d12905ce07e7-7fff.html) on how to set font directory.